# SignalR is not working when deployed on server

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm working with signalr. it works in my local server and in my project but when i deployed it in the main server it does not work at all.

Here is what I see when I view source the `/signalr/hubs`

**Local Server**

```
proxies['iTestHub'] = this.createHubProxy('iTestHub'); 
proxies['iTestHub'].client = { };
proxies['iTestHub'].server = {
  checkChanges: function () {
  return proxies['iTestHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['iTestHub'], $.merge(["checkChanges"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
  }
};
```

**Main Server**

```
proxies['iTestHub'] = this.createHubProxy('iTestHub'); 
proxies['iTestHub'].client = { };
proxies['iTestHub'].server = {
};
```

I don't know why this part of the code gone.

```
checkChanges: function () {
  return proxies['iTestHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['iTestHub'], $.merge(["checkChanges"], $.makeArray(
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

I've put `checkChanges` function in my `hub`.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: can you write us how are you deploying your server? maybe some dlls are missing?

Comment: actually i just copied everything from my local to main server.. is it ok to do that?

Comment: when ever i do that everything is ok upon copying from my local to server.

Comment: have you copied the release version? are you sure that you have correct .NET installed on the server?

Comment: yes it is the .net version.. 4.5 version is in my main server pool same as my local server

Comment: Make sure you are not doing any cross-domain things without enabling CORS.

Comment: @DatzMe did you find any solution?